# What language is XNA implemented in?

Tags: xna, libraries

One interfaces with XNA through C#, but does anyone know what language the library itself is implemented in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the former XNA lead, [Shawn Hargreaves](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/12/29/what-should-i-write-about-next.aspx):

> much of XNA itself is written in C++

By this, I expect that Shawn specifically means [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), given that the vast majority of XNA is managed code.

The unique feature of C++/CLI is that it is very good for writing code that bridges between the native and managed universes, including features that aren't available from C#. In particular you can mix native and managed code in the one assembly, and call native code directly from managed code.

XNA makes extensive use of DirectX (plus a few other things), which is native code, thus making C++/CLI an excellent choice.

Of course, XNA handles all the native stuff so that you don't have to. Stick to C# wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I'd been searching for a while with no luck.